# Sets Subset Proof Connections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This may be a very stupid question, but I will still ask and hope to get some bits of help (If this is not the right place, please let me if there is a better site for this kind of question) Thank you.

We need to prove that $A = B$, where $A = 4x+1$ and $B=4y-3$ Where Y and X ∈ integers as two sets.

Given guide is to prove A and B is subset of each other.(define Y in terms of x)

let $n$ is an element of $A$, then there exits some $X$ is element of integers such that $n =4X+1.$ Show that n is an element of B by showing there there exists an integer m such that n = 4m-3.

let just set up two equations as $n=4X+1, n =4Y-3.  4X+1=4Y-3. 4y=4X+1+3, y=(X+1).$ Since X is integer and 1 is integers, then X+1=y is also an integer.

My questions are:

1. Did I complete the proof of $A\subset B$ ? (if not, what is missing?)
2. Why showing $n\in B$ (by showing that there exists an integer $Y$ such that $n = 4x-3$) also fulfills $n\in B$ means that $A\subset B$ ?

Comment: Looks fine (with very cumbersome notation...), but after $\;Y=X+1\;$ , we could summarize: "Thus, $\;n=4X+1=4(X+1)-3\in B\;$" .

Comment: Question 2 is wrongly asked (or ill-posed, as mathematicians use to say). It should be: " why showing that **any** $\;n\in A\;$ also fulfills $\;n\in B\;$ means that $\;A\subset B\;$?" , and the answer is: because that **exactly** is the definition of $\;A\;$ being a subset of $\;B\;$: that any element in $\;A\;$ is also an element of $\;B\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you vary much.  Appreciated your inputs and help me learn how to ask the questions the right ways.

Comment: Your notation is nearly incoherent.  Learn the proper notation for sets.